# Where is ros.h supposed to be found?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, rosmake, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to compile a c++ ROS node with no luck.

I keep getting an error of cannot find ros/ros.h

I tried creating a new node with roscreate-pkg add pasted in the code from the talker tutorial.

Even though my new package is found by ros, It will not build..

```
/scratch/ros/publisher/src/publisher.cpp:1:21: error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory
```

I have installed ros-diamondback-all  from apt on Ubuntu 10.04. The only mention of ros.h is in

```
/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/ros.h
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9653/where-is-ros.h-supposed-to-be-found?/) by [dave_haddon](https://answers.ros.org/users/384/dave_haddon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2011-04-05

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll answer my own question...

It doesn't matter where ros.h is.

In the manifest.xml for the package, add

```
<depend package="roscpp"/>
```

And all will be well...

---

Originally posted by [dave_haddon](https://answers.ros.org/users/384/dave_haddon/) with karma: 156 on 2011-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrea019](https://answers.ros.org/users/27520/andrea019/) on 2016-07-17**:
Hello.. im sorry I am totally new with this.. I have the same error.. where is the manifest.xml file supposed to be? I dont have anything similar in my package folder  :(

**Comment by [Equaltrace](https://answers.ros.org/users/25519/equaltrace/) on 2016-07-31**:
Did you find out manifest file? It is the package.xml file for your package.

**Comment by [Paddre](https://answers.ros.org/users/29218/paddre/) on 2017-01-31**:
But for that it need to be `<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>` (according to the description of the generates package.xml). This still did not solve the problem for me though :-(

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-31**:
@Paddre: this is a VERY old question and refers the the manifest.xml that was used with rosbuild. If you're using catkin the instructions are different; you need a build_depend in your package.xml, and you need to add roscpp in your CMakeLists.txt .

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-31**:
If you're still having trouble please **ask a new question** instead of reopening an old question.